# Passing derivative through integral of a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve an exercise on Folland's book of real analysis on the part of fourier transforms and its applications on PDE's, when working with the heat equation one may show that given the heat kernel
$$G_t(x)={(4\pi t)}^{-n/2}\exp\left( - \frac{\mid x \mid ^2}{4t}\right)$$ and some function $f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ s.t.

$$|f(x)| \leq C_\epsilon \exp(\epsilon \mid x \mid^2) $$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

I've shown that the convolution $u(x,t) = f \ast G_t (x)$ is well defined and trying to show  now that this function solves the equation $(\partial_t - \Delta)u  = 0 $ on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0, \infty)$.

It is easy to show that $G_t$ satisfies this equation, but is it possible to pass with the derivative trough the convolution s.t.

$$ (\partial_t - \Delta)u(x)= (\partial_t - \Delta)\int f(y)G_t(x - y) dy = \int (\partial_t - \Delta)f(y)G_t(x - y) dy = f \ast (\partial_t - \Delta)G_t (x) = 0$$

If so this part of the exercise will be done, but i don't have this kind of result as $G_t$ does not have compact support, so how can i show this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to your question, but why is $f \ast (\partial_t - \Delta)G_t (x) = 0$?

Comment: Because $G_t$ satisfies the equation and so $(\partial_t - \Delta)G_t = 0$, this is easy to show trough fourier transform and the fact that $G_t$ is in Schwartz space

Comment: Oh, I see. You're taking a convolution with the zero function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to take the derivatives inside the integral. Compact support is not really necessary for this type of proof - rapid spatial decay of $G$ and its derivatives is good enough. To justify the operation, do it manually by taking difference quotients: for instance,
$$
\partial_t \int f(y)G_t(x-y)~dy = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left[ \int f(y)G_{t+h}(x-y)~dy - \int f(y)G_t(x-y)~dy\right].
$$
You want to show that the limit on the right is well-defined and equal to
$$
\int f(y)\partial_t G_t(x-y)~dy.
$$
This can be done using dominated convergence, using the fact that $f\in L_{\operatorname{loc}}^1$ and $\partial_t G_t$ decays rapidly in space to find an appropriate integrable dominating function. You would do similarly for the Laplacian, taking one derivative at a time.

Comment: Okay, will try it, if anything comes i try commenting here

Comment: I can get a limitation of the type $C e^{\epsilon |y|^2} / (1+|x-y|)^N$ where $\epsilon$ is arbitrary $|y|$ can be made larger than a constant, but i don't know how to proceed

Comment: It sounds like you're not using the quadratic exponential decay of $G_t$ well enough. Try being more efficient in your estimates on $G_t$ and its derivatives.

Comment: My definition of decay is $|\partial^\alpha G_t(x)| \leq C_N (1+|(x)|)^{-N}$, is it about a better choice of N or something else?

Comment: Polynomial bounds are not good enough to defeat your growth bounds from $f$, which grows as a quadratic exponential. But $G_t$ and its derivatives have Gaussian decay, so you can do much better than any polynomial bound.

Comment: So maybe work on the terms rather than applying some mean value inequality?

Comment: There's not that much work to do though. You can do mean value if you want - there are lots of ways to get this done - but ultimately you're still going to have something that looks similar to $\exp(\epsilon|y|^2)\exp(-|x-y|^2/4t)$ with possibly other factors. It should not be difficult to show that this is integrable for a judicious choice of $\epsilon$, as long as you're not just throwing away the Gaussian decay.

Comment: yeah i done this to work with well defined convolution, basically taking a ball of radius $|x|+1$ and looking outside of it works in this case, for the inner part as it is compact things goes smootlhy, i'm kind of stuck with the $h$ that appears on the denominator, that's why i used the mean value, ill try and work on it more later